# javascript to show the selected image in jsp page

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

i use the below java script code to preview the selected image in the jsp page it works in firefox and ie 11 but not works in ie9 is there any alternate way to make it work in ie9

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function PreviewImage() {
        var oFReader = new FileReader();

to check jpg file start
        var fileInput = document.getElementById("imageId").files[0];
        if (fileInput.type.match('image/jpeg')) 
            
        {
       
        }else{document.getElementById("imageId").value='';
        alert("Please Select a Image File.");
        return false;
        }

to check jpg file end
       
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("imageId").files[0]);

        oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            document.getElementById("upImgId").src = oFREvent.target.result;
        };
    };

</script>
```

```html
<s:file name="hr_Family_Information_Bean.image" id="imageId" label="Image" required="true" onchange="PreviewImage();"/>


    
       <img class='imagem_artigo' id="upImgId" src="data:image/png;base64,${hr_Family_Information_Bean.imageEncodeData}" alt="Image Not Found" height="220" width="165" title="${hr_Family_Information_Bean.memberName}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using filereader that is not supported by ie9
pls tak a look at:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=filereader

You should use some polyfill (sth that works also on IE9)Here is a list pls use the one that is the most appropriate for you.

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#file-api